# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:25.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-support-design

Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:25.0.1

ERROR- this support library should not use a different verion(25) than the compileSdkVersion(28)

```
  dependencies {
       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
       implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- layout:1.1.2'
       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
       core:3.0.2'

    //add library
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
}
```

Comment: try `compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-beta01'`

Comment: I did, this is showing now: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2] C:\Users\h\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-ui-0.6.2.aar\84f7ed608b610d3a6c07ea2571ca66a0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15

Comment: this suggestion is showing -     Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
  or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
  or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Comment: change `minSdkVersion 16` in build.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libraries from same "group" or referencing each others, must use the same version (when possible). Support llibraries, in particular, must have the same version of your compiled one.

You have `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'` that is targeting a `28 Beta version` and `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'` targeting `25 version`.

Also you are probably using `compileSdkVersion 28`.

Implement support:design library to refer to version `28.0.0-beta01` too and it will (probably) will be fixed.

in shorts, use this gradle snippet:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//add library
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
```

(use `implementation` instead of `compile` since it will be replaced soon)

Hope this helps. Let me know if this solved!

## Edit from comment below

Why are you using old versions? is there a reason?

increase firebase version also, the last should be 4.1

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'
```

Comment: I did the same but after syncing this shows: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2] C:\Users\hp\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-ui-0.6.2.aar\84f7ed608b610d3a6c07ea2571ca66a0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
 Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
  or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
  or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Comment: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0] C:\Users\hp\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-ui-database-4.1.0.aar\35f2453636c0d9c1cf2fc620ff9a897d\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
 Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
  or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
  or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui.database" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Comment: @BTSJimin no problem, consider marking the answer as the solution to help other people with the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
```

with

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```